# Is it possible to create a filter that filters out distinct values in a dataset?

Tags: ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a report that will contain two pie charts. I get the data for the report from SQL. 
Currently, I created a dataset for the first chart which holds records with the following fields: Import ID, Date, Status. This dataset contains duplicate records. 
For the second chart, I need the same data I have in the first dataset, only without duplications and aggregated differently. 
I realize that I can create another dataset that will get the distinct values from the SQL database, but I was wondering if there was a way to use the built-in filtering functionality to filter out the dataset I already have to return only distinct values (based on ID field). 
Looking at the options in the following filtering dialog, I see no obvious way to do this:

[image]

Comment: Please - provide more info and say - if ID field is UNIQUE? - what kind of duplicity you have in 1st case and what you want to get in 2nd - provide two examples as small datasets

Comment: The ID field is not unique. The dataset contains something similar to this:  
    ID     Date       State  
    1      10.12.11    1  
    1      11.12.11    1  
    1      12.12.11    1  
    2      12.12.11    3      
    2      13.12.11    3  
  
etc..  
  
I'd like to get the following after filtering by id:  
    ID      State  
    1          1  
    2          3

Answer (score 0):

If ID is not unique and your 1st query looks like this:

```
select ImportID, Date, Status
from YourTableSource
WHERE YourConditions
```

Then you probably should use for your 2nd query form like this:

```
select DISTINCT ImportID, Status
from YourTableSource
WHERE YourConditions
```

If changing the query is not an option ,then you may create the Group in ssrs with invisible DETAIL pane and place the ID and Status fiels in int Group pane

Comment: @user1039580 Edited to meet your conditions, does it fits?

Comment: That will work, the question is - is there a way to do the filtering on the report side?

Comment: If there is an internal variable such as GroupRowNumber or any other ordinality inside the group, then use it, otherwise - why reporting should work an excessive data out?

Comment: There's no internal variables defined. I can define one if that will help achieve my goal. 
I want to filter out data from the dataset for the second chart in which I only want to aggregate unique records from the dataset.